# How to make a python script run in Anacron

Tags: python, cron, crontab

I have a python script that I would like to run daily using anacron, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

The script is in my home directory, and I have put a symlink to it in /etc/cron.daily/. I saw somewhere that things here can't have dots in the filename, so the symlink has the .py extension removed (the original file still has it).

The python file does have #!/usr/bin/python on the first line.

This is my first experience with cron / anacron, and so I'm sure I'm making a dumb mistake - I just don't know what it is. Is a symlink a problem? Do I need the actual file there? Is the python script the problem? Do I need to run a bash script that will open the python script? Is there something else I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dumb question, but is your script executable? Right click on file and then Properties. In Permissions tab ther should be checkbox to set script as executable.

Comment: Thanks very much! I knew it was something dumb. I checked the permissions on the symlink, and I assumed that the permissions represented the permissions on the original file.

Changing the permissions on the original file looks to have done the trick!

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: Symlinks do not have permissions.  `ls` will show them as having all permissions enabled, but this is (basically) a lie.  The kernel only cares about the permissions of the target, and will never use the symlink's permissions.